# flask: hashes "#" in the routing

Tags: python, url, flask, routes, url-routing

I'm working with google API lately and use simple flask method to retrieve some id_token.

here is my code with explanations in comment:

```
@app.route('/afterlogin/id_token')
def afterlogin(id):  # get the id
    print(id)  # print it 
    return render_template(r'creds_view.html', data=id) # and render the template with 'id' in it (for test purposes)
```

So what happens is that after the user logins, the api redirects the `id_token` to `http://localhost:8000/afterlogin/#id_token=some_id_token`.

but for some reason it is showing me 404 error.
i think it is because of the '#' in the url , i want the `id_token`. i know that '#' in html means for path linking or routing in 'href'.

so for that i tried.

```
@app.route('/afterlogin/<path:id>')
```

but the error still persists.

any guesses?

Comment: Everything after the `#` in the URL  is not sent to the server, you can't use it in routing.

Comment: @Barmar submit that as an answer

Comment: I've checked it manually by trying `http://localhost:8000/afterlogin/#hello` and it showed me not found, moreover the interesting thing is that when i try `http://localhost:8000/afterlogin/hey#hello` it prints `hey`

Comment: @jamylak I don't know Flask, so I don't know how to correct what he's doing.

Comment: Query params seems to be the obvious alternative then

Comment: @jamylak can you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: thanks i figured it out, i removed the parameters in 'afterlogin' like app.route('/afterlogin')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything after `#` is processed locally by the browser, it's not sent to the server, so you can't use it in routing. Leave out the `#`:

```
http://localhost:8000/afterlogin/some_id_token
```